# Jquery: Validate Form not working in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I am in the process of building my own business site, and I want to have form validation without refreshing the page. I am following [this video from youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wUu7pWBygY&feature=relmfu) to help accomplish this goal. However, it works perfectly in Chrome but will not work in Firefox. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thank You!

Here is my javascript to validate my form:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fname').keyup(function() {
                $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=fname', { fname: form.fname.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $('#fname-error').html(result).show("slow");
                });
            });

            $('#lname').keyup(function() {
                $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=lname', { lname: form.lname.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $('#lname-error').html(result).show("slow");
                });
            });

            $('#zipcode').keyup(function() {
                $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=zipcode', { zipcode: form.zipcode.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $('#zipcode-error').html(result).show("slow");
                });
            });

            $('#city').keyup(function() {
                $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=city', { city: form.city.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $('#city-error').html(result).show("slow");
                });
            });

            $('#email').keyup(function() {
                $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=email', { email: form.email.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $('#email-error').html(result).show("slow");
                });
            });

            $('#username').keyup(function() {
                $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=username', { username: form.username.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $('#username-error').html(result).show("slow");
                });
            });

            $('#password').keyup(function() {
                $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=pass', { pass: form.password.value }, 
                function(result){
                    $('#password-error').html(result).show("slow");
                });
            });

            $('#password2').keyup(function() {
                var pass1 = $('#password').val();
                var pass2 = $('#password2').val();

                if( pass2.length < 5 ){
                    $('#password2-error').html("Too short!").show("slow");
                }
                else if(pass2 != pass1){
                    $('#password2-error').html("Didn't match!").show("slow");
                }else{
                    $('#password2-error').html("<img src='images/check.jpg' />").show("slow");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is part of my sign up page form:

```
<div class="signup-page">
       <form id="ContactForm" action="#" name="form">                                                                           
       <h2><img src="images/mail.jpg" alt="Sign up to SittersCaregivers.com" width="23"  height="24" >Contact Information</h2>

           <div class="hr"></div>                                              
           <div  class="wrapper">                                                
               <div class="error-div" id="fname-error" ></div>                                               
               <label>First name:</label>                                                
               <input type="text" class="input" name="fname" id="fname" />                                          
           </div>

           <div  class="wrapper">                                               
               <div class="error-div" id="lname-error" ></div>                                              
               <label>Last name:</label>                                                
               <input type="text" class="input" name="lname" id="lname" />                                          
           </div>

           <div  class="wrapper">                                               
               <div class="error-div" id="zipcode-error" ></div>                                                
               <label>Zip code:</label>                                             
               <input type="text" class="input" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" />                                          
           </div>

           <div  class="wrapper">                                               
               <div class="error-div" id="city-error" ></div>                                               
               <label>City:</label>                                             
               <input type="text" class="input" name="city" id="city" >                                         
           </div>

           <div  class="wrapper">                                               
               <div class="error-div" id="email-error" ></div>                                              
               <label>Email Address:</label>                                                    
               <input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email">                                                                                                
           </div>                                           

           <div  class="wrapper">                                               
               <div class="error-div" id="username-error" ></div>                                               
               <label>Username:</label>                                             
               <input type="text" class="input" name="username" id="username" />                                            
           </div>

           <div  class="wrapper">                                               
               <div class="error-div" id="password-error" ></div>                                               
               <label>Create Password:</label>                                              
               <input type="text" class="input" name="password" id="password">                                          
           </div>

           <div  class="wrapper">                                               
               <div class="error-div" id="password2-error" ></div>                                              
               <label>Confirm Password:</label>                                                 
               <input type="password" class="input" name="password2" id="password2">                                                                                                
           </div>


           <div class="hr"></div>                                                                                

           <p>By clicking Continue, you agree to our Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. 
           You'll also receive account updates and special offers from Sittercity.com 
           which you can opt-out of at any time. </p>

           <div  class="wrapper">                                           
                <input type="submit"  class="submit" value="Continue" name="Submit"id="submit"/>                                                            
           </div>                                       
       </div>
</form>
```

And here is some of my dummy validation. It's just a sample validation.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['key'])){
        $key = $_GET['key'];

        switch($key){

            case 'fname':  
                    if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
                            $fname = $_POST['fname'];
                            if(empty($fname)){
                                echo " *First Name Required";   
                            }elseif(strlen($fname)<3){
                                echo "*Name too short!";
                            }else{
                                echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
                            }
                    }
                    break;


            case 'lname':

                    if(isset($_POST['lname'])){
                            $lname = $_POST['lname'];
                            if(empty($lname)){
                                echo " *Last Name Required";    
                            }elseif(strlen($lname)<3){
                                echo "*Last name too short!";
                            }else{
                                echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
                            }
                    }
                    break;


            case 'zipcode':

                    if(isset($_POST['zipcode'])){
                        $zip = $_POST['zipcode'];
                        if(empty($zip)){
                            echo "*Zipcode required!";
                        }elseif( (strlen($zip)<5) OR (strlen($zip)>5)){
                            echo "*Must be 5 digits!";
                        }elseif(!is_numeric($zip)){
                            echo "Must be numeric!";
                        }else{
                                echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
                        }

                    }
                    break; 


            case 'city':

                    if(isset($_POST['city'])){
                                $city = $_POST['city'];
                                if(empty($city)){
                                    echo "*City Required";  
                                }elseif(strlen($city)<5){
                                    echo "*Too short!";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
                                }
                    }
                    break;


            case 'email':

                    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
                                $email = $_POST['email'];
                                if(empty($email)){
                                    echo "*Email Required"; 
                                }elseif(strlen($email)<5){
                                    echo "*Too short!";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
                                }
                    }
                    break;

            case 'username':

                    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
                                $username = $_POST['username'];
                                if(empty($username)){
                                    echo "*Username Required";  
                                }elseif(strlen($username)<5){
                                    echo "*Too short!";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
                                }
                    }
                    break;

            case 'pass':

                    if(isset($_POST['pass'])){
                                $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                                if(empty($pass)){
                                    echo "*Password Required";  
                                }elseif(strlen($pass)<5){
                                    echo "*Too short!";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<img src='images/check.jpg' />";
                                } 
                    }
                    break;


            Default: return false;break;

        }

    }else{
        //do nothing
        return false;
    }



?>
```

Comment: what error do you get in the error console?

Comment: You'll want to post some code so we know what we're looking at. Your question needs more detail.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and/or a jsFiddle example, otherwise your question is useless.

Comment: What code are you using? What errors is it showing in the error console? Do you have a preview page we can have a look at?

Comment: Hi gurus : please see the dummy page at http://www.gtwebworx.com/layout/signup.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would neccessarilly use form.name.value in your post AJAX. Try $(this).val() instead. Leverage the jQuery to remove cross browser issues.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try using bind('keyup change blur'), function(){}); instead of .keyup
also I'm not sure it's necessary to check on every keystroke, I would use a timer function to see if they are done typing, this is something I use on my site that should give you a good starting point:

```
 var typingTimer;
 var doneTypeingInterval = 1000; //time in milliseconds for timeout
 $(function () {
    $("input").bind('keyup mouseup change', function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if ($(this).val) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){checkingFunction($(this))}, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });      
 });

 function checkingFunction($object){
     //do checking with your object here
     var id = $object.attr('id');
     $.post('action/validate_signup.php?key=' + id, { value: $object.val() }, 
            function(result){
                $('#' + id  + 'error').html(result).show("slow");
            });
 }
```

obviously i have no real way of testing this, but on the whole it should work more efficiently than what you had.  Note that I changed the object being sent to value instead of the name of the thing being sent, you can change how you handle that server side, using the key that you also passed in.

Comment: im using .change and .blur but nothing happens

Comment: you don't have a link to it or a jsfiddle equivalent do you? It would be helpful to see the html as well

Comment: oh God, that code is something strange on my part. I'm a newbie in jquery.

Comment: Im sorry jeff, but I dont have.

Comment: hmm.. try changing $(document).ready()(function() { to $(function() {  The only thing I could get it to say erroring was "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'"

Comment: I updated my answer, see if the javascript there will work for you

Comment: Thanks Jeff,..It really works however it's a bit confusing code for me as  newbie  I follow @jfable's solution and surely it works.